# Sort and rank a dataframe by grouping each unique user and adding a visit number column for each unique date Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am fairly new to Python and I am trying to add a visit number column in a list of users from my data frame.

I have a dataframe of 55 unique users specified by the 'UserID' column and a datetime column indicated by 'dateStarted'
I want to create a column that for each user and each unique date there is a a visit number. The dataframe should look like:

```
  UserID dateStarted  visit
0      a    01/01/10      1
1      a    01/01/10      1
2      a    01/04/10      2
3      b    06/02/08      1
4      b    07/15/12      2
5      c    02/12/12      1
6      d    02/12/12      1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Avoid using images. Your previous copy paste of text was perfect. Just needs to be formatted as code. Please revert back to the previous edit

Comment: `df.groupby(['UserID','dateStarted']).cumcount() +1` ?

Answer (score 1):

Group the dataframe by `UserID` and `rank` the values in `dateStarted` to assign ordinal values.

```
df['visit'] = df.groupby('UserID')['dateStarted'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
```

---

```
  UserID dateStarted  visit
0      a    01/01/10      1
1      a    01/01/10      1
2      a    01/04/10      2
3      b    06/02/08      1
4      b    07/15/12      2
5      c    02/12/12      1
6      d    02/12/12      1
```

Comment: I got an error that states 'no numeric types to aggregate'

Comment: @RebeccaNetson What is your pandas version?

Comment: I fixed it by adding a mapping function and first sorting by user id and datestarted posted below:
df1 = df.sort_values(['UserID', 'dateStarted'], ascending=[True, False])
df1['date_rank'] = df1.groupby(['UserID'])['dateStarted'].transform(lambda x: list(map(lambda y: dict(map(reversed, dict(enumerate(x.unique())).items()))[y]+1,x)) )